# How to disable CKEditor's source code view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, rails-admin

I have a rails app with CKEditor integrated with rails admin and paperclip, but I need disable the source code view option to prevent javascript injection. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the plugin from the config.js file. (or comment out)

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/config.js

possibly `'sourcearea'` var.

Comment: Or add to `config.removePlugins`.

PS. It's impossible to prevent JS injection. It's a JS app so there are hundreds of ways to inject JS.

Comment: Thanks for help this really disable source editor, but this also disable the integration of ckeditor and paperclip gem.